# using SQLBulkCopy with CSV and quoted identifier

Tags: c#, sql

I have some code that reads in a CSV file, loads that information to a data table, and then uses SQLBulkCopy to send it to SQL server.  This is working fine except when my data has a column with a quoted identifier.

Here is the record that is causing the problem:

```
17,1,1,2,B219483,1,Martinez,Don,,Female,1965-01-30 00:00:00.000,915 Main St,Apt 7,Anywhere,CO,8000-1111,0,717-241-7766,1,,2,1,,0,,Reason for opting out per Health Co. - "214453, dr c johnson is not a part of the ACC"

,NULL,ENG,NULL,NULL,2011-07-18 15:50:48.000,1,2011-08-26 10:26:35.077,7
```

Notice there is a column of data that has a comma in the data so the entire column has double quotes.  The problem is that my program will fail when I get to that line of data with this message:
System.ArgumentException: Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

What options do I have to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> 17,1,1,2,B219483,1,Martinez,Don,,Female,1965-01-30 00:00:00.000,915
>   Main St,Apt 7,Anywhere,CO,8000-1111,0,717-241-7766,1,,2,1,,0,,Reason
>   for opting out per Health Co. - "214453, dr c johnson is not a part of
>   the ACC",NULL,ENG,NULL,NULL,2011-07-18 15:50:48.000,1,2011-08-26
>   10:26:35.077,7

From looking at your data, it seems the double quotes are only around part of the data for that column.  The double quotes should begin before *Reason* rather than *214453*.